Conductor of hyperelliptic curve after base change
Let $r\geq 5$ be a prime, and let $\zeta$ denote a primitive
$r$-th root of unity. Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Suppose I have computed the conductor exponent $n$ of $C/\mathbb{Q}$ at $r$.
I now base change $C/\mathbb{Q}$ over the number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$.
I am interested in computing the conductor exponent $n'$ of $C/K$ at $\mathfrak{p}_{r}$, where $\mathfrak{p}_r$ is the prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$ above $r$. Are there any known results concerning the relationship between $n$ and $n'$?

A few comments: (1) In general, you'll need more information. (2) If $n=0$, then clearly $n'=0$. (3) Restricting to $r\ge5$ isn't enough to simplify the problem. So let's assume that $r>2g(C)+1$, which will put us into the tame ramification case. (4) Then if $C$ has split totally semi-stable reduction at $r$, then I think that $n'=en$, where $e$ is the ramification index of $K/\mathbb Q$. But I haven't actually checked. (This is true for elliptic curves.) (5) It's possible (I think) for $C/\mathbb Q$ to have bad reduction, i.e., $n\ge1$, but for $C/K$ to have good reduction, so $n'=0$.

Ah, I should have added that the genus of the curve is equal to $\frac{r-1}{2}$. So it seems that there is no "easy shortcut" to get from $n$ to $n'$ - this is useful to know, thank you!
